# The domain of FFT

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

I have a real signal $f(t) $that is periodic on $[0,L]$ where $L=1$. I sampled it uniformly $64$ times and computed FFT (in python). I was asked **to find the frequency where the transformed signal is having  the largest magnitude**. I found the index $i$ of the largest value in the transformed signal.

How do I find the frequency (in hertz ) corespondent to  the index $i$ ? My thinking is that my frequency domain must be $64$ uniform samples on $[-32/L,31/L]=[-32,31]$ and therefore the central frequency is $$f=i-32$$.

To support my claim I run the following code to get the frequency domain:

```
import numpy as np
num_samples = 64
L=1
freqs = np.fft.fftfreq(num_samples, L/num_samples)
print(np.fft.fftshift(freqs))
```

which yields:

[-32 ,-31 ,-30 ,-29 ,-28 ,-27, -26 ,-25 ,-24, -23 ,-22 ,-21, -20 ,-19
-18 ,-17 ,-16 ,-15 ,-14 ,-13 ,-12 ,-11, -10 , -9 , -8  ,-7 , -6 , -5
-4 , -3  ,-2  ,-1  , 0  , 1 , 2  , 3  , 4 , 5  , 6  , 7 ,  8 ,  9
10 , 11 , 12 , 13 , 14 , 15 , 16  ,17  ,18 , 19 , 20 , 21 , 22 , 23
24 , 25  ,26  ,27 , 28 , 29 , 30 , 31]

However my answer was not accepted by the TA. They claimed that the frequency domain is
$64$ uniform samples on $[-\pi*32,\pi*31]$  and my answer is wrong.

Who is right ?

Edit March-15-2024 - made it clear we are looking for the frequency that maximizes the transformed signal.

Comment: Perhaps it is a units thing?

Comment: We need to find the central frequency in hertz.

Comment: Then I would agree with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, assuming that frequency is measured in Hertz.

Suppose $N$ is even for simplicity, and there is a collection of samples $g_0,...,g_{N-1}$. If $n \mapsto \hat{g}_n$ is the DFT, then we can write
$g_k = \sum_{n=-{N \over 2}}^{{N \over 2}-1} \hat{g}_ne^{i2 \pi {n k \over N}}$.

In the case given $g_k = f(k {L \over N} )$, so letting $t=k {L \over N} $, we have
$f(t) = \sum_{n=-{N \over 2}}^{{N \over 2}-1} \hat{g}_ne^{i2 \pi {n kL \over N L}} = \sum_{n=-{N \over 2}}^{{N \over 2}-1} \hat{g}_ne^{i2 \pi {n \over L}t}$. Hence the frequencies are ${n \over L}$ with $n = -{N \over 2},...,{N \over 2}-1$, and so the frequency of largest magnitude occurs are $n=-{N \over 2}$ and is $f_\max=-{N \over 2L}$.

In your example, $N=64, L=1$ and so $f_\max = 32$.

Comment: How can you conclude what is f_max without knowing what are $g_0, ....  g_{N-1} $ ?

Comment: @Tomer The $g_k$ have nothing to do with the frequency of maximum magnitude. Since $f$ is not specified, I am interpreting the question as "what is the frequency of maximum magnitude that can occur for **any** $f$".

Comment: The question is , given index i of the entry with maximum magnitude of the transformed signal - what is the frequency of the maximum magnitude of the transformed signal. Namely, how do you map the index i to a frequency. I think that in my case  $ f_{max} = i -32$

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. The question asked what is the frequency of largest magnitude, and that is $32$. If you are asking about the mapping of the numpy.fft array to frequency, then that is $i \mapsto {i-{N \over 2} \over L}$ (when $N$ is even), which in this case is $i \mapsto i-32$.

Comment: Yes my question is related to the mapping of the index to frequency and we agree  it is i -32.  I need to fix my question. It is not the frequency with the largest magnitude but the frequency so that f^(w) is maximal where f^ is the transformed signal.